# Numpy not printing array precisely in scientific notation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scientific-notation

i'm trying to multiply all entries of a matrix with a number with many decimal places. But numpy keeps returning the rounded value and not the precise one in scientific notation... e.g. it should be d*g0[0] = -0.59999... but it returns -0.6 directly

```
g1 = np.array([5.61608209, 426.8222385])
g2 = np.array([43.76305474, 325.09697808])

g0 = g1-g2
print(g0) # returns [-38.14697265 101.72526042]

d = 0.01572863999999998
g = d * g0
print(g) # returns [-0.6  1.6]
```

I've seen that theres numpy.around() and numpy.set_printoptions() with suppress and precision. But those are all to make the printed output in decimal format, what if I want numpy to make it more precise and in scientific notation?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In this specific case you can use unpacking `print(*g)` or , if you insist for scientific notation, `print('%18.11e %21.12e'%(*g,))`